# What are the fewest passing yards by quarterbacks in an NFL playoffs win?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, postseason, quarterback

At the end of the Tennessee Titans victory against the Baltimore Ravens in the divisional round of the 2019-2020 playoffs, the commentators announced that Ryan Tannehil became the first Quarterback to throw for less than 100 yards in back to back playoff victories. Tannehil threw for [72 yards](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=gc4aXt7nEtK0tQbY2ruADQ&q=tennessee%20titans&oq=tennessee%20titans&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i131i67l2j0i131l8.30503.32884..32991...1.0..0.196.1730.12j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i3j0j0i273j0i67.lOxIvvcSQUk&ved=0ahUKEwierJLMyP3mAhVSWs0KHVjtDtAQ4dUDCAo&uact=5#sie=m;/g/11fkthcwjn;6;/m/059yj;dt;fp;1;;) against the New England Patriots in the wild card round. And he threw for [88 yards](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=gc4aXt7nEtK0tQbY2ruADQ&q=tennessee%20titans&oq=tennessee%20titans&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i131i67l2j0i131l8.30503.32884..32991...1.0..0.196.1730.12j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i3j0j0i273j0i67.lOxIvvcSQUk&ved=0ahUKEwierJLMyP3mAhVSWs0KHVjtDtAQ4dUDCAo&uact=5#sie=m;/g/11h112gkx3;6;/m/059yj;dt;fp;1;;) against the Ravens.

This makes me wonder what are the 5 lowest passing yards by winning quarterbacks in any NFL playoff game? I'm considering quarterbacks who started the game and finished it (includes those who were benched at the end of the game if the team was winning by a big margin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Joe Flacco - BAL, 34 yards, Wild Card - Baltimore Ravens at New England Patriots - January 10th, 2010
2. Craig Morton - DAL, 38 yards, Divisional Round - Detroit Lions at Dallas Cowboys - December 26th, 1970
3. Mark Brunell - WAS, 41 yards, Wild Card - Washington Redskins at Tampa Bay Buccaneers - January 7th, 2006
4. Otto Graham - CLE, 43 yards, Divisional Round - New York Giants at Cleveland Browns - December 17th, 1950
5. Dieter Brock - LAR, 50 yards, Divisional Round - Dallas Cowboys at Los Angeles Rams - January 4th, 1986

[Source](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=game&year_min=1950&year_max=2019&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=QB&is_starter=E&game_type=P&career_game_num_min=1&career_game_num_max=400&qb_start_num_min=1&qb_start_num_max=400&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&game_result=W&qb_started=Y&c1stat=pass_yds&c1comp=lt&c1val=99&c2stat=pass_att&c2comp=gt&c2val=5&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_yds) - may require a subscription to view

Comment: Looking at your source, it appears there have been instances where the QB threw for 17, 21, 31, and another 34 yards, which would be less than (or equal) to the list in this answer.

Comment: You are not considering your own criteria.  My list contains only starters that played a full (or nearly full) game

Comment: That's great! The sourced table doesn't have any indication if the QBs started the game or not.

Comment: Had to research each game log.  And there's no field you can set to sift it out.  Glad to help.